# mongoose pre saved bcrypt not saved

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bcrypt

I've an issue with bcrypt and mongoose pre save function.

my log tells me, everything is fine hashed... but mongoose doesn't save the new hashed password properly.

`do post save 6BYpYJtD
POST /api/v1/user 200 26.999 ms - 387
do pre save 6BYpYJtD $2a$10$OgNaou5y8JO2v4ErcZN4v.2cG9LOPjgJKzptvrKXVgCBRrrFsMHMO`

to make things clear:
`6BYpYJtD` is my generated password, `$2a$10$OgNaou5y8JO2v4ErcZN4v.2cG9LOPjgJKzptvrKXVgCBRrrFsMHMO` is the hash generated by my pre save function:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var user = this;
        user.updated_at = Date.now;
    if(user.isModified('password'))
    {
        bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR,function(err,salt){
            if(err) return next(err);
            bcrypt.hash(user.password,salt,function(err,hash){
                if(err) return next(err);
                console.log('do pre save',user.password,hash);
                user.password = hash;
                console.log(user.password);
                next();
            });
        });
    }

    return next();
});
```

there are no errors printed so i'm really not aware, of what could be my error here. any advice?

Comment: field `password` has just the declaration for `type: String`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hours of hours of hours of debugging later, is just found the solution to my issue:

after altering the password information you need to `return next(user);` with your user object as parameter. now it works like a charm.